# Setting fixed width for tab in tabwidget

Tags: android, tabwidget

Searched for this a lot but am unable to find a satisfactory answer. My application is using a tab widget and I want to make the width of each tab equal. There are about 6-8 tabs in my main activity ad i have also added a horizontal scroll view. I want it to look somewhat like the built in task manager for android or the manage applications settings layout. Currently the size of the tab is equal to the length of the tab title. What can be done?
Thankyou.